# Meaning of correlation in Markov process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, correlation

I have been told that a Markov process $X_1,X_2,\dotsc$, where $X_i\in \{1,-1\}$  with correlation $\rho$ satisfies
$$ \mathbb{E}(X_i\mid X_{i-1})=\rho X_{i-1} $$
But am I correct in saying that this does *not* necessarily imply $\mathrm{corr}(X_{i},X_{i-1})=\rho$?

My reasoning is as follows: I get $\mathbb{E}(X_iX_{i+1})=\rho$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\rho\mathbb{E}(X_{i-1})$, so that
$$\mathbb{E}\left[(X_i-\mathbb{E}(X_i))(X_{i-1}-\mathbb{E}(X_i))\right]=\rho-\rho\mathbb{E}(X_{i-1})^2$$
and
$$\mathrm{Var}(X_i)=1-\rho^2\mathbb{E}(X_{i-1})^2,\qquad \mathrm{Var}(X_{i-1})=1-\mathbb{E}(X_{i-1})^2$$
and so
$$\mathrm{corr}(X_{i},X_{i-1}) = \frac{\rho(1-\mathbb{E}(X_{i-1})^2)}{\sqrt{(1-\rho^2\mathbb{E}(X_{i-1})^2)(1-\mathbb{E}(X_{i-1})^2)}}=\rho\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1-\mathbb{E}(X_{i-1})^2}{1-\rho^2\mathbb{E}(X_{i-1})^2}}\neq \rho$$

Comment: $\text{corr}(X_i,X_i)=1$

Comment: @Philipp123 Ooops, I meant $\mathrm{corr}(X_i,X_{i-1})$ and have edited the question.

Comment: You may be reading what they're calling "correlation" a bit too literally, they may just intend it to be "a parameter that determines the level of correlation" even though there is a nonlinear (but monotone!) relationship between the parameter $\rho$ and the correlation coefficient.

Comment: Does the process have to be stationary, so that the expected value is zero, making the fraction equal to one?

Comment: @Ian That would make sense, thank you.

Comment: @Joe This was not specified in the article (an application to finance), but I suspect that we may in fact take the process to be stationary, which would also solve the problem. Thank you!